# Solr: find ULR and port

Tags: solr

I have solr-4.10.3 installed in my Ubuntu server, I have forgot the URL and port.

Where can I find this infos in my Solr config files ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The admin UI should be accessible at

http://localhost:8983/solr

Default port: 8983

To change a port

```
java -Djetty.port=9999 -jar start.jar
```

**For solr 5.4.1 for example**

solr-5.4.1\bin\solr start -p XXXX

Please visit https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Go inside your Solr directory. Navigate to example folder,As per your Solr insatance it will be like solr-4.10.3/example/

then start your Solr instance from Ubuntu terminal using command

`java -jar start.jar`

Open browser and hit URL

```
http://localhost:8983/solr
```

Answer (score 0):

Solr admin URL has a pattern `http://localhost:{port-number}/solr/#/`

You can verify the port number by browsing to bin folder where you have installed solr and checking the PORT file as shown below :

[image]

In above example, the solr admin can be accessed by URL https://localhost:8989/solr/#/ (Note depending on how solr is configured try using http or https)

[image]